# Checking distance between items of list taking too much time. Is there a way to make it faster?

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

I'm following [Sebastian Lague's Procedural Landmass Generation tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDQK1_SWFuc) . He is generating landmass' color by height value. But I want to separate landmass to a array or list as areas by their color. Because the way Sebastian use generates too many water or mountain areas so I want to make them less. I tried to edit the code of him but the code I made tooks 2-3 minutes to separate. Does anyone have idea to make it faster?

The class I use to seperate regions and the areas in every region:

```
public class Positions
{
    public int regionID;
    public int areaID;
    public int x;
    public float y;
    public int z;
}

List<Positions> positions = new List<Positions>();
```

The code I try to find and list them:

```
    for (int y = 0; y<mapChunkSize; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x<mapChunkSize; x++)
        {
            float currentHeight = noiseMap[x, y];
            for (int i = 0; i<regions.Length; i++)
            {
                if (currentHeight <= regions[i].height)
                {
                    int areaID = 0;
                    if(positions.Where(x => x.regionID == i).Count() != 0)
                    {
                        areaID = getNeighourIndex(i, x, y);
                    }
                    Positions p = new Positions { regionID = i, areaID = areaID, x = x, y = noiseMap[x, y], z = y };
                    positions.Add(p);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    int getNeighourIndex(int regionID, int x, int y)
    {
        List<Positions> pos = positions.Where(x => x.regionID == regionID).ToList();
        if (pos.Where(q => Vector2Int.Distance(new Vector2Int(q.x, q.z), new Vector2Int(x, y)) <= 1).Count() > 0)
            return pos.Find(q => Vector2Int.Distance(new Vector2Int(q.x, q.z), new Vector2Int(x, y)) <= 1).areaID;

        return (pos.Select(q => q.areaID).OrderBy(x => x).LastOrDefault()) + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Try changing positions to be a dictionary. `List<Positions> positions` => `Dictionary<int, List<Positions>> positions` where key is `regionID` and access elements by region id instead of searching for then every time.

Comment: Use [`ToLookup()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-6.0) to improve performance of getting all elements in `positions` by region id: `var positionsByRegion = positions.ToLookup(p => p.regionID);`. Then replace linear searches like `positions.Where(x => x.regionID == regionID)` with `positionsByRegion[p.regionID]` for constant time position retrieval.

Comment: Thanks for reminding the Dictionary, I forgot that one but I tried that right now and yeah there is a little improvement but it's 20 sec. I think I should fine another way.

I'll check ToLookup(), but I think it seems like the dictionary at least for me. But again I'll check that one either. Thank you

Comment: You're also calculating the distance twice with `Vector2Int.Distance()`. Do it only once with `FirstOrDefault()`: `pos.FirstOrDefault(q => Vector2Int.Distance(...) <= 1) ?? pos.Select(q => q.areaID).OrderBy(x => x).LastOrDefault() + 1;`.

Comment: Also avoid allocations. You're only doing `ToList()` so you can use `Find()` even though you don't really need it. `Distance()` only accepts two `Vector2Int`s even though it probably also could accept four `int` values.

Comment: Oh you right, maybe calculating more than 2 in if statement

Comment: Yeah I changed format that I use to search. This time I use  those +(0,1) +(1,0) +(-1,0) +(0,-1) to find neighbour but It still searching in large list so It tooks too much time. At least It's faster 20 sec than usual :d

Answer (score 2):

As always when doing optimizing, the first step should be to measure, ideally with a profiler since this can hint at what it is that takes most time.

But I would guess that the majority of the time is spent in `positions.Where(x => x.regionID == regionID)`. To solve this you could use a multi value dictionary, i.e. a dictionary where each key can map to multiple values. It is fairly easy to make your own wrapper around a `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>`, or you could use one from [Microsoft.Experimental.Collections](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/blob/archive/src/Microsoft.Experimental.Collections/Microsoft/Collections/Extensions/MultiValueDictionary.cs).

You could also consider using a hierarchical search structure for the points, like a kd-tree, quad-tree or similar.

Also, if performance is of high importance, using LINQ is likely not the best option. LINQ is convenient, but the abstraction adds some overhead. In most cases this overhead is irrelevant, but in tight loops like this it may very well be a significant factor.

Comment: I think there are too many points that I even can't write. Tbh 2-3 min is good but not ideal. I tried to dictionary and it took less 20 sec than usual but still not ideal. (Btw thank you too reminding dictionary). I'll check those your recommendations. Thank you again

Comment: @Utku I would really recommend using a profiler, or add a bunch of stopwatches to monitor time. Your example code looks quite inefficient, and there should be plenty of opportunities for optimization, but you really need to know what the current bottleneck is in order to provide good recommendations.